# How to use bootbox.alert to stop executing the function

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have such code(in Javascript):

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        var http = getHTTPObject();
        if (http) {
            var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
            for (var foo = 0; foo < anchors.length; foo++) {
                if (anchors[foo].className == "httpauth") {
                    createForm(anchors[foo]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    function createForm(jshttpauth) {
        var form = document.createElement("form");
        form.action = jshttpauth.href;
        form.method = "get";
        form.onsubmit = login;
        form.id = httpauth.id;
        var username = document.createElement("label");
        var usernameInput = document.createElement("input");
        usernameInput.name = "username";
        usernameInput.type = "text";
        usernameInput.id = httpauth.id + "-username";
        username.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Username:"));
        username.appendChild(usernameInput);
        var password = document.createElement("label");
        var passwordInput = document.createElement("input");
        passwordInput.name = "password";
        passwordInput.type = "password";
        passwordInput.id = httpauth.id + "-password";
        password.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Password:"));
        password.appendChild(passwordInput);
        var submit = document.createElement("input");
        submit.type = "submit";
        submit.value = "Log in";
        form.appendChild(username);
        form.appendChild(password);
        form.appendChild(submit);
        jshttpauth.parentNode.replaceChild(form, jshttpauth);
    }

    function login() {
        var username = document.getElementById(this.id + "-username").value;
        var password = document.getElementById(this.id + "-password").value;
        this.http.open("get", this.action, false, username, password);
        this.http.send("");
        if (http.status == 200) {
            document.location = this.action;
        } else {
            bootbox.alert("wrong username/password");
        }
        return false;
    }
</scritp>
```

I'm using this code to achieve http authentication with html forms.But the problem is that this code doesn't display `bootbox.alert ("Wrong username/password")` on my `login.html` page, the `login()` function is just continue to execute, returning false (I included bootstrap library in my html). But when I use `alert()` function it works just fine. I don't know how to fix this. Any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated.